# Preventing ASP.NET viewstate from being transmitted in querystring via form GET

Tags: asp.net

I believe I have disabled the view state on all controls as well as the page itself, but the querystring still contains the __viewstate and __eventvalidation parameters.

Any ideas on what to check and/or change? Is there something I may not know about viewstate (very likely) that is causing the view state to be transmitted in the form GET method?

Thanks,
Kevin

Edit:

I am using the GET method because I would like the form results to be able to be bookmarked, linked, etc.  This is not possible with Post simply because the form data isn't transmitted via the URL.

And I prefer the viewstate/eventvalidation not shown simply for aesthetic reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing the `runat="server"` attribute from the form tag will effectively remove the hidden viewstate and eventvalidation fields. But then you can't use server controls on the page, so I doubt that's what you want to do.

Are you sure the __viewstate and __eventvalidation fields appear in your *querystring*?? That does sound a bit strange.

Post some code and tell us why you want to remove the hidden fields in the first place. If you disable viewstate on a page-level, the values in the hidden fields should remain relatively small...

Comment: I think he's made the forms method 'GET', not 'POST'. Bit weird, but that's why it's in the QueryString.

Comment: My guess too: That's why I would like to see the source, it's probably not a regular .aspx as created by default by VS...

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant by "via form get"
Sorry, sometimes things make sense in my head then when I type them, they make less sense.

I will update the question with the requested information.

Comment: This was the easiest way to make sure there is no viewstate information being transmitted.

I removed the server tags and all is well.

Comment: Excellent. Next time I'll remember to read the WHOLE title of the question. The bad was on my side. :)