# Prevent Viewstate from being sent as a query string in asp.net site

Tags: asp.net, viewstate, pageload, request.querystring

I have a dot.net website and the big search engines seem to want to try and index www.example.com/page.aspx?__VIEWSTATE=lotsofrandomstuffhere

Now I thought I could simply on page load or init check Request.Querystring for __VIEWSTATE or VIEWSTATE and just redirect but this doesn't seem to work.

Any idea how to catch this error ?

I tried this without success

```
Protected Sub Page_PreInit(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.PreInit
If Request.QueryString("VIEWSTATE").Length > 0 Then
Response.Redirect("woli.aspx")
End If 
End Sub
```

Tried on Pageload and using __VIEWSTATE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check your Form submission method if it is GET then change into POST

```
<form method="get">
```

change into

```
<form method="post">
```

Comment: Yup - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309610/preventing-asp-net-viewstate-from-being-transmitted-in-querystring-via-form-get

Comment: Changing to POST does solve the initial problem but as ever throws up a few new ones :) Thanks