# How to use a form with GET to utilize querystring, but not have VIEWSTATE in querystring?

Tags: c#, query-string, viewstate

I'm trying to create a C# webpage that uses a GET method so I can bookmark form data, email it to other people, etc., but changing the form method to GET results in the querystring containing the VIEWSTATE.  I can take out the runat=server tags (as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309610/preventing-asp-net-viewstate-from-being-transmitted-in-querystring-via-form-get)) but then I don't know how to set the values of my form fields.  I don't mind manually persisting them, but I can't figure out how.

So, how do I either utilize the viewstate but keep it out of my querystring, or access the form controls without runat=server?

Comment: just disable viewstate for your page, but keep runat="server" on the controls

Answer (score 0):

If you are using, for example, a search/filter form on your webpage that you want via GET, here's a pattern I've used multiple times in my own code.  When the user submits a button to process what they've entered in the form, I let it hit my code-behind as a POST as normal.  Then I manually construct a GET request and redirect to it:

```
protected void BtnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var query =
        "?filter1=" + TxtFilter1.Text +
        "&filter2=" + TxtFilter2.Text +
        "&filter3=" + TxtFilter3.Text; // etc.
    Response.Redirect(query);
}
```

Then on load of the page, I process the entries in the query string to pre-populate the relevant form controls on the page:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        TxtFilter1.Text = Request.QueryString["filter1"] ?? "";
        TxtFilter2.Text = Request.QueryString["filter2"] ?? "";
        TxtFilter3.Text = Request.QueryString["filter3"] ?? "";
        // etc.
    }
}
```

This allows me to have control over what actually goes into the QueryString without messing with the built-in form POST managed by ASP.Net (including View State).  Also, when a user has filled out the form and pressed the button, they have a linkable url, and even though it was a POST, if they refresh the page they don't get that annoying message about re-sending data to the server.